# Using string function inside google sheet script

Tags: string, google-sheets

How to extract substring from string and length of a string?

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use the MDN website to search for those but here is what you asked for :

> extract substring from string

The [`substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) method returns the part of the [`string`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) between the start and end indexes, or to the end of the string.

```js
const str = 'Stephano';

console.log(str.substring(1, 3));
// "te"
console.log(str.substring(2));
// "ephano"
```

> length of a string

The [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length) property of a [`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) object contains the length of the string :

```js
let string = "This is text !"
console.log(string.length)
// 14
```

Comment: thank you!!
This is my code that doesn’t work  function cat(ma)
{
    l= ma.lenght
  return l;
}

Comment: The function works? The problem isn't on the function itself but on how you use it. Try `cat('Test')`

Answer (score 1):

This is the file with the example functions.
Now it works, thanks to the valuable advice

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12jX8aAH5pkUYHFduBT8ueaebymcrACX0gdqBf5Xyl48/edit?usp=sharing

```
function cat(ma)
{
    ll = ma.length;
        
    return ll;
}

function tr(m)
{
    lll = m.substring(2,9);
        
    return lll;
}
```